# Draw mutiple histograms for multiple sub-category in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataset like this,

```
col1   col2
A        5
A        7
A        1
A        6
B        2
B        9
B        8
...
Z        4
```

I tried to draw multiple histograms to take a look at the distribution for each sub-category in `col1`.

Additioally, how can I do this if I want to choose only the most 10 frequent sub-categories in python?
For exmaple, I can use `value_counts()` to calculate the amount for each sub-category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy.size`, sort the values and select the first `n`. ANd user the index to plot a histogram containing only the mentioned groups:

```
ix = df.groupby('col1').size().sort_values(ascending=False).head(2).index
df[df.col1.isin(ix)].groupby('col1').hist()
```

Comment: Hi, yatu. Thanks for your help. Do you know how to add their group names on the title for each group using this method?

Comment: Thank you I found that. `.hist(by=df['col1'])`